# Namespace inherited from include file in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

For a statistical package, I need to include a numerical computation library, and I chose Armadillo. I want to keep all the dependencies to Armadillo in a single "wrapper" file (to be able to switch numerical libraries easily). At the moment the wrapper to Armadillo, called `mixt_LinAlg.h` only contains:

```
#ifndef MIXT_LINALG_H
#define MIXT_LINALG_H

#include "mixt_Typedef.h"

#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

namespace mixt {

template<typename T>
using Matrix = Mat<T>;

template<typename T>
using Vector = Col<T>;

template<typename T>
using RowVector = Row<T>;

}

#endif // MIXT_LINALG_H
```

This way, if I import this header, I have access to `Matrix`, `Vector` and `RowVector` templated classes, without importing Armadillo directly. Now, in Armadillo there is a function `arma::approx_equal`, which takes two `Col<T>` for example, and returns a `bool`.

If I simply call this function using `approx_equal` instead of `arma::approx_equal`, it  compiles with Clang on macOS. But when I compile it with GCC on Ubuntu, it complains that it can not find `approx_equal`.

How can I make `approx_equal` available to any file that includes `mixt_LinAlg.h`, without having to reference the `arma` namespace in the including file ?

Comment: don't put "using namespace anything" into a header - you'll regret it later.

Comment: I find it curious that GCC can find `arma::approx_equal` but not `approx_equal`, given that your `using namespace arma` is valid for any file including `mix_linalg.h`.

Comment: Actually, even doing what Kaveh proposes in his answer, GCC still can not find arma::approx_equal either.. I do not understand what is going on here. I am using GCC 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: With Clang 3.8.0 on Ubuntu I have the same problem, but not with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0

Comment: And finaly, on macOS the code compiles even without using namespace arma and specifying the arma:: namespace for approx_equal...

Comment: Works as expected with both clang and gcc [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d430655583ece12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your header your own function `approx_equal` in your own namespace, which wraps around  `arma::approx_equal` or any other implementation.

In other words add something like this to you header for Armadillo:

```
... my_namespace::approx_equal (...) {
    return arma::approx_equal(...);
}
```

You'd have to have one of these wrappers for every implementation you'd like to be able to switch to.